# Update Textblock with number of active Tasks in ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I'm trying to create a status window that shows the user how many tasks are currently running. Each task gets added to an ObservableCollection and I have the binding path set in the window XAML, but the box does not update. I've searched extensively for a good working example or tutorial on how to accomplish this and I can't find anything. What am I doing wrong? It's a program to connect to each Cisco Switch in our office and download the configuration file, by the way.

The window XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="BackupCiscoConfigs.ProcessRunning"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:BackupCiscoConfigs"
        Title="ProcessRunning" Height="300" Width="300"
        Closed="Window_Closed" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">

    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Run" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="btnRun" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="btnRun_Click" />
        <TextBlock Width="200" Height="85" Margin="35,80,43,65" Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=d1.results.Count}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Window codebehind:

```
namespace BackupCiscoConfigs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ProcessRunning.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ProcessRunning : Window
    {
        private MainWindow m_parent;
        private Configuration currentConfig;
        public DeviceInterface di;

        public ProcessRunning(MainWindow parent)
        {
            currentConfig = Configuration.loadConfig();
            m_parent = parent;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnRun_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<Device> devices = currentConfig.devices;
            di = new DeviceInterface(currentConfig.tftpIP,
                currentConfig.tftpDIR, currentConfig.cmd);
            di.RunCommands(devices);
        }
    }
}
```

Class generating the tasks:

```
namespace BackupCiscoConfigs
{
    public class DeviceInterface
    {
        private string tftpIP;
        private string tftpDIR;
        private string command;
        private string dirDate;
        public ObservableCollection<Task> results { get; set; }

        public DeviceInterface(string tftpIP, string tftpDIR, string cmd)
        {
            this.tftpIP = tftpIP;
            this.tftpDIR = tftpDIR;
            this.command = cmd;
            dirDate = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy.HH.mm.ss");
            Directory.CreateDirectory(tftpDIR + dirDate);
        }

        public void RunCommands(List<Device> devices)
        {
            results = new ObservableCollection<Task>();
            foreach (Device d in devices)
            {
                Device d1 = d;
                d1.command = command + " tftp://" + tftpIP + "/" + dirDate + "/" + d1.ip + ".cfg";
                results.Add(Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => d1.BackupDevice()));
            }
            string res = "";
            foreach (Task<string> t in results)
            {
                string message = t.Result + "\n";
                res += message;
            }
            MessageBoxResult msg = MessageBox.Show(res);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Window x:Class="BackupCiscoConfigs.ProcessRunning"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:BackupCiscoConfigs"
        Title="ProcessRunning" Height="300" Width="300"
        Closed="Window_Closed" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">
        <Button Content="Run" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="btnRun" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="btnRun_Click" />
        <TextBlock Width="200" Height="85" Margin="35,80,43,65" Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=Results.Count}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Window codebehind:

```
namespace BackupCiscoConfigs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ProcessRunning.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ProcessRunning : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private MainWindow m_parent;
        private Configuration currentConfig;
        private DeviceInterface di;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property. 
        // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName 
        // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument. 
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<Task> _results;
        public ObservableCollection<Task> Results
        get
        {
            return _results;
        }
        set
        {
            _results= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("results");
        }

        public ProcessRunning(MainWindow parent)
        {
            currentConfig = Configuration.loadConfig();
            m_parent = parent;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnRun_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<Device> devices = currentConfig.devices;
            di = new DeviceInterface(currentConfig.tftpIP,
                currentConfig.tftpDIR, currentConfig.cmd);
            di.RunCommands(devices);
            Results = di.results;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even with this it won't work because there's no such property as `d1`. Also I think the correct `DataContext` binding will be `{Binding Source={StaticResource DeviceInterface}}` for your example.

Comment: Ah, yeah. I think he wants results.Count. The DataContext should work as it is above.

Comment: Not until he implements `INPC` on top of `results` which is kinda what i said in my own answer :) Also I noticed he has no parameterless constructor for DeviceInterface so he can't do it in xaml like your example suggests without adding a new constructor

Comment: The example will need to be aided by a parameterless constructor... unsure sure how you want to implement it.

Comment: @narohi I'm on C#4/.NET4 so I don't think I can use the [CallerMemberName] attribute

Comment: @Taj G Edited to add .NET 4 INPC.

Comment: well for that much effort, you have my +1 :)

Comment: @narohi I appreciate the effort, but the code you posted does not update the textblock with the number of items in the collection.

Comment: Lol, thank you. I realize now that I have been on the wrong track with my answer... sorry Taj G. I do not think my approach will give you the results you want. It looks as if you should set to data context to a relativesource of self and bind to the d1 property in your codebehind instead of setting the datacontext to the DeviceInterface class. Need to get back to work, so I cannot provide any more example code.

Comment: `private DeviceInterface di;` needs to be `public DeviceInterface di;` if you wish to bind to it.

Comment: `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"`

Comment: @narohi I made the deviceInterface class public and changed the datacontext as you suggested, but nothing changes.

Comment: @narohi That does not work. The issue I think is with the binding. If I try to use the design editor to bind the text of results.Count it cannot resolve the path.

Comment: Try Results.Count instead of results.count

Answer (score 0):

Two problems that I can see immediately:

1. I can't see where you're setting up `DataContext` for this path to work: `Path=d1.results.Count`
2. You're updating `results` property but you're not implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` which means WPF will never know you've hooked a new `ObservableCollection` into results.

Comment: I'm not looking to update when a property gets changed, just when the collection gets changed (total number of tasks in the collection). My understanding is that the point of using an ObservableCollection<T> is that it exposes INotifyCollectionChanged. I tried setting up the DataContext but it still doesn't work.

Comment: `results = new ObservableCollection<Task>();` doesn't only change the collection... it creates a new one. `results` could be null on the initial binding and then WPF will never know the variable has been instantiated without have a notification.